# What will happen after timeout when using Observable.timeout?

Tags: java, rx-java, reactivex

I have an `Observable` that go to database and query for some information. I don't want my observable executes longer than 5 seconds, thus I use:

```
myObservable.timeout(5,second);
```

Then I want to handle the error notification also, thus I use:

```
myObservable.timeout(5,second).onError(return empty result);
```

Then I wonder for what will happen to the code in `myObservable` that is used to do database query. Will it also be terminated, or it will continue to run ? (which happens to Java native `Future.get(timeLimit)`)

Comment: You probably could answer this question yourself quite easily. Set up an Observable that just sleeps for 10 seconds, and try the above code, see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

Let's take an example :

```
Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .timeout(10, TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS)
            .onErrorReturn(e -> -1L)
            .subscribe(System.out::println,
                       Throwable::printStackTrace,
                       () -> System.err.println("completed"));
```

the `timeout` operator will emit an error. But precedent operators won't be notifier of this error.

The operator `onErrorReturn` will transform your error to an event and then will complete your stream (and mark it as finished) and then your source observable will be unsubscribe.

This unsubscription part will run some code that, depending of how your source observable is written, that may stop your request, or just do nothing, or free some resources.

In your case, it may call the `cancel` method on your `Future` (according to the [Subscriptions](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/1.x/src/main/java/rx/subscriptions/Subscriptions.java#L96) class)